# Как загрузить JSON файл в Angular?

Tags: json, angularjs, google-docs

Добрый день, проблема в том что хочу загрузить JSOn файл с гугл документа но в ответ мне приходить ерудна , не объект , а просто код всего гугл документа в текстовом формате ,такого вида :
Можно ли как то просто этот текст преобразовать в JSON?
Или что я делаю не так?

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("mainController", function($scope, $http){
 
 
 
 $http.get('https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YWYIP1_1mL3qWjBKaueWbvwfGB54AOD0aj2Rt6MQdNM/edit',).then(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data.data;
    console.log(data.data)
  });
 
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{{countries}}</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Потому что json нельзя так хранить. Внутри док файла. Нужно создать json файл

Answer (score 0):

Создайте на компьютере текстовый документ, положите в него Ваш json и загрузите его на drive.google.com. После этого необходимо для этого файла получить ссылку для совместного доступа (правой кнопкой мыши по файлу -> совместный доступ) вот такого вида:

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/file_id/edit?usp=sharing
```

В этой ссылке присутствует идентификатор файла **file_id**

Теперь этот идентификатор нужно подставить в ссылку такго вида в самый конец:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=
```

Должно получиться вот так

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=file_id
```

Теперь по этой ссылке Вы сможете получить Ваш json.